# I want handle CUPS authentication using Basic authtype, how to custom PAM?

Tags: linux, pam, cups

I'm using simple pam on github(https://github.com/beatgammit/simple-pam).
And in my project, i want handle CUPS authentication using PAM, So i change /etc/pam.d/cups

from:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

to:

```
auth sufficient testpam.so
account sufficient testpam.so
```

when i auth but failed,and i got CUPS error like this:

```
[17/Feb/2014:19:24:50 +0800] cupsdAuthorize: pam_authenticate() returned 6 (Permission denied)!
[17/Feb/2014:19:24:52 +0800] cupsdAuthorize: pam_authenticate() returned 6 (Permission denied)!
```

Is there something wrong about your simpe pam? or i must implement something?

Answer (score 1):

already fixed it by change cups config file, make it allow in privilege config.

Comment:  I feel sad of my question stay here alone for 7 years and 8 months

Comment: Don't feel bad, technically it was Off-Topic for this site and would have been proper on any of [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). That contributed to it living such a long life.

Comment: Thanks a lot David,  your hint is really helpful 